# Is Drupal 7 a good fit for my site?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I started creating my site in Wordpress 3.1, and I have hit a speed bump. I am considering switching to EE or Drupal 7, in hopes of achieving my vision of the site.

The problem I am having is excluding terms in the dropdown menu query. Currently I have taxonomies for CarMake, CarModel, Year, etc... My problem is when I select Honda, the  menu does not exclude non Honda cars, so you get a giant list of car models.

The search menu then would return all "posts" that include those taxonomy terms in the "Videos" custom post type. Each "post" was essentially a blog post with a very short description and a youtube video.

Before I invest countless hours learning Drupal or EE, I would like to find out how hard this menu/search would be to implement. An example of the menu I would like to re-create is [here](http://www.wingswest.com/catalog/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module does exactly what you describe. [Here is a demo](http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy) that even uses car brands as the example.

Comment: That's fantastic! Do you know if it works with multiple taxonomies? This would be required because I have other atributes that I need to include in the search. It looks like the sample is setup to use one taxonomy and then show the first terms parent.

Comment: That's not really how taxonomies work, and not just in a Drupal-specific way. The terms wouldn't have any relation to each other, so you couldn't use them to exclude each other.

Comment: Hmmm, am I going about this in the wrong way? For example I need to query with a search menu, find posts that have the car "Honda Civic EX" that also have a spoiler and custom wheels. Since the spoiler and custom wheels are not specific to that car, i'm not sure how to organize them. I originally had the Car make, model, trim in a single taxonomy, but with Wordpress being wonky, the menu I have only worked with them in separate taxonomies.

Answer (score 2):

From your last comment on tim.plunkett's answer, I think you're pretty much there. You can use a single taxonomy with [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) for the Make, Model and Trim. Then you can use a separate taxonomy for the Category dropdown. Since the Category terms aren't specific to a car, they should go into a separate taxonomy.

Comment: Interesting. Would the Hierarchical Select first display results for Car>Make>Model>Trim and then from there, use the category dropdown to select AccessoryBrand>Model to further refine the search?  I'll have to research this some more :)